# How to execute cron quartz for the first Saturday and the first Sunday of each month

Tags: date, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have tried with:

```
0 0 2 ? 1/1 SAT#1,SUN#1 *
```

but the result is wrong (only appears the sunday):

1. Sunday, April 6, 2014 2:00 AM
2. Sunday, May 4, 2014 2:00 AM
3. Sunday, June 1, 2014 2:00 AM
4. Sunday, July 6, 2014 2:00 AM
5. Sunday, August 3, 2014 2:00 AM

also I have tried with:

`0 0 2 1-7 * ? SAT,SUN`  and a lot of variants but all of them are invalid syntax.

The correct output should be:

1. Saturday, April 5, 2014 2:00 AM
2. Sunday, April 6, 2014 2:00 AM
3. Saturday, May 3, 2014 2:00 AM
4. Sunday, May 4, 2014 2:00 AM
5. Sunday, June 1, 2014 2:00 AM
6. Saturday, June 7, 2014 2:00 AM
   .
   .
   .
   .

I've been doing all the tests since http://www.cronmaker.com/ (nice page!) unsuccessfully.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron Quartz definitely not allowed to do this in a single statement. I get error message: "Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented."

Answer (score 0):

I've tried unsuccessfully too. In my opinion, Quartz Cron has some limitations.

By the way, can't you split your cron into two different schedules? For example:

```
0 0 2 ? 1/1 SAT#1 *
0 0 2 ? 1/1 SUN#1 *
```

Comment: thank you Pablo Anaya. I need a single statement. So I tried to do a work around like '0 0 2 1-7 * ? SAT,SUN' unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

`0` and `7` stand for Sunday.

Hence, the numbers from `1` to `6` are fixed to `Monday`, ..., `Saturday`.

Graphically:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

**0 0 1-7 * 0,6 ***  should work for you.

[Cron](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm)

Comment: this is a not correct answer. I am using http://www.quartz-scheduler.org and its syntax is different from the original :'(. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to split it to 2 cron expressions. From the documentation ( http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html ) :

> If the '#' character is used, there can only be one expression in the day-of-week field ("3#1,6#3" is not valid, since there are two expressions).

Comment: thank you przno. I need a single statement. So I tried to do a work around like '0 0 2 1-7 * ? SAT,SUN' unsuccessfully.